# How to exclude a pattern that starts with a phrase, but the pattern may contain substring of the phrase?

Tags: regex

With this example,

```
whether or not apple
apple
not apple
```

How could I find either `apple` or `not apple` and exclude `whether or not apple`?
My attempt was to use negative lookbehind like

```
(?!whether or not)(([Nn]ot)?\s*apple)
```

but this finds all as

- whether or `not apple`
- `apple`
- `not apple`

Comment: `^(?!whether or not)(([Nn]ot)?\s*apple)` seems to work, but wonder if there are other ways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your consuming pattern starts with an optional pattern, you need to account for these two scenarios and implement two separate lookbehinds:

```
(?<!\bwhether or )(?<!\bwhether or not )(?:\bnot )?\bapple\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ee952N/3). *Details*:

- `(?<!\bwhether or )` - no `whether or`  allowed immediately on the left
- `(?<!\bwhether or not )`  - no `whether or not`  allowed immediately on the left
- `(?:\bnot )?` - an optional sequence of `not` word and a space
- `\bapple\b` - a whole word `apple`.

Another approach is to match the string you want to skip and skip it:

```
\bwhether\s+or\s+not\s+apple\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\bnot\s+)?\bapple\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ee952N/4). Here, `\bwhether\s+or\s+not\s+apple\b` matches the `whether or not apple` and `(*SKIP)(*F)` drop the match, skips to the position of the failure and restarts a new match search.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are looking for is `^(?:not\s)?apple`

#### Python

```
import re

re.match(r"^(?:not\s)?apple", "apple")  # matches
re.match(r"^(?:not\s)?apple", "not apple")  # matches
re.match(r"^(?:not\s)?apple", "whether or not apple")  # does not match
```

#### JavaScript

```js
/^(?:not\s)?apple/.test("apple"); // matches
/^(?:not\s)?apple/.test("not apple"); // matches
/^(?:not\s)?apple/.test("whether or not apple"); // does not match
```